# Vanilla JavaScript + multiple select - getting the same value on multiple selections?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, multiple-select

Why we always get the **same** value and index for multiple select when you hold down the `ctl` key to multiple-select the options?

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  console.log(this.selectedIndex)
  console.log(e.target.value)
})
```

```html
<select name="books[]" multiple>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

This happens when you multiple-select the options from **top down**. I would expect it to get new value and index but not the same. It is ok when you do it from **bottom up**.

How can we get the 'expected' value and index  when you multiple-select the options from top down?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is [`tree order`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/infrastructure.html#tree-order)

> The `selectedIndex` IDL attribute, on getting, must return the index of
>   the first option element in the list of options in tree order that has
>   its selectedness set to true, if any. If there isn't one, then it must
>   return −1.  [`Ref`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#attr-select-multiple)

Same is true for `value`

> The value IDL attribute, on getting, must return the value of the
>   first option element in the list of options in tree order that has its
>   selectedness set to true, if any. If there isn't one, then it must
>   return the empty string. [`Ref`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#attr-select-multiple)

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  console.log(this.selectedOptions)
  console.log(e.target.value)
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

```html
<select name="books[]" multiple>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Mamun `selectedOptions` is used to show how the `tree order` looks like when you select multiple options, `selectedIndex` returns the `index` of first option ( selected ) from the tree order

Answer (score 1):

According to [The select element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-select-element.html)

***select .*** `selectedIndex` ***[ = value ]***

> Returns the index of the ***first selected item***, if any, or −1 if there is no selected item.
>   Can be set, to change the selection.

From the above, the term ***first selected item*** indicates that there can be multiple selected items but it will only return the first index.

Comment: But why it happens `top down` not `bottom up` ?

Comment: @CodeManiac, *first selected item* is not the one you have selected first, rather it is based on the order it appears in the select....

Comment: But i don't see anywhere this is mentioned as first index option, can you please lead me to the docs ?

Comment: @CodeManiac, the output itself describes that.....why do want that to be in the doc?

Comment: This can be one such case it's happening this way, to be sure this will happen the same way in all the cases, i asked for reference, and i found this here [`tree order`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/infrastructure.html#tree-order)

Comment: @CodeManiac, since it is not mentioned explicitly in the linked doc, I doubt that could be mentioned anywhere.... also, until unless I am getting the output other way, I will stick to this:)

Comment: Yes this is mentioned in docs, you can read [`here`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#attr-select-multiple)

Comment: @CodeManiac, I could see anything related to your point with `selectedIndex` in the link....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197439/discussion-between-code-maniac-and-mamun).

Answer (score 1):

You should be using selectedOptions and grab their index value:

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < this.selectedOptions.length; i++) {
    console.log( this.selectedOptions[i].value);
  }
})
```

```html
<select name="books[]" multiple>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

If you want the result from bottom to top, then just reverse the loop:

```js
    document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      for ( var i = this.selectedOptions.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        console.log( this.selectedOptions[i].value);
      }
    })
```

```html
<select name="books[]" multiple>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is due to [`tree order`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/infrastructure.html#tree-order), `The selectedIndex IDL attribute, on getting, must return the index of the first option element in the list of options in tree order that has its selectedness set to true, if any. If there isn't one, then it must return −1.`